# Is firebase UID and document ID contain only numbers and letters?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**First Question,**
I need to know, Is a UID(example - `5c7tlagMDoVSACVyO8S867V2sbl2`) and Document ID(example - `dA852BlJI9eJhyQywlLB`) only contains letters and numbers? or it would be changed if the users increased or documents increased?

**Second Question**, Is UID length and Document ID length can be changed if the documents increased or users increased?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking about the IDs automatically generated by the Firestore SDK when you do an `add()` operation, you can be sure that they will contain only letters and numbers, and will have a consistent length.  The IDs are generated **randomly on the client**, not on the server.  The generated IDs have nothing to do with the number of documents in the collection, or any other factors.

There are overall constraints on document IDs in Firestore, which are covered in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#collections_documents_and_fields).